# parse json nested dict items in python based on item type

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary

I'd like to list the value from the "name" key only based on the value of "Username" from key "type" from a local json file stored in a variable called result (using json.load(input_file). The file contains other non username dictionaries that I don't want in my result.

```
   {
        "count": {
            "references": {
                "returned": 10,
                "total": 17933
            }
        },
        "entities": {
            "KF4UXbl": {
                "name": "johndoe123",
                "type": "Username",
            },
            "KeirTr": {
                "name": "#thash123",
                "hits": 141581,
                "type": "Hashtag",
            },
            "SQsD6o": {
                "name": "goodie1234",
                "type": "Username",
                "modified": "2019-04-12T21:02:51.938Z"
            },
            "type:Speech": {
                "name": "Other",
                "type": "MetaType",
            },
            "QXyWAK": {
                "name": "textuser1234",
                "type": "Username",
            },
            "type:Topic": {
                "name": "Topic",
                "type": "MetaType",
            },
            "KeTJkZ": {
                "name": "TestOrg",
                "type": "Organization",
                "meta_type": "type:Organization",
            },
}
```

Code

```
for i, j in result.iteritems():
 if j.get('type') == 'Username':
  print j.get('name')
```

However I get this error:

```
    if j.get('type') == 'Username':
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

How can I print out the below based on the value of Username?

```
johndoe123
goodie1234
textuser1234
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: my question is, based on the json dict above, how do I print a list of names from the 'name' key based on the value of 'Username' from key 'type' ?

Comment: If the dictionary you posted is exactly what `result` is, then `result` is a nested dictionary. The top level keys are `"count"` and `"entities"` which both point to values that are their own dictionaries. Try replacing `result.iteritems()` with `result.get("entities").iteritems()` in your `for` loop definition. This should iterate over the part of the data structure you're interested in.